# React JS: Fetching data from REST server with dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, reactjs, url-parameters

I've built a small React component that fetches json data from REST service with ajax call.

In [tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#fetching-from-the-server) you can change to component data prop to url where you can fetch the data from:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox url="/api/comments" />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Now, the problem is that the REST API requires parameters in following way:

```
/api/resource/parametervalue
```

Meaning that the data which is fetched from the server changes according to the parameter.

The parameter that needs to be passed to the REST API is in the PATH of the current URL in following way:

```
/mywebsite/dynamicparameter
```

One way to do it would be getting url parameters with javascript:

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var lastParameter = pathArray.pop();
var url = "/api/resource/"+lastParameter;
```

And passing that url variable to the component:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox url={url} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I've investigated [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/Introduction.md) but I'm not sure if it really helps in this problem.

What would be best and most elegant way to represent and define React component data url with parameters? Is there React solution to this?

Comment: Do you mean something like, `<CommentBox url={"/api/comments/" + dynamicparameter} />`?

Comment: @David Tryon yes that's exactly what I mean

Comment: So, are you asking how to get the dynamic parameter from the url?  Or how to make the `CommentBox` attribute `url` dynamic?

Comment: @David Tryon Basically I'm asking both. There is ofc different solutions to get dynamic parameter from URL, but I'm wondering if there is React solution to this instead of plain javascript. Another question is how to make component attribute url dynamic